# Turning an ambiguous grammar to an unambiguous one

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I understand the topic and how to do it, but then I stumbled upon this example which is: The context-free grammar that describes all words that have the string ab in them. The grammar is

$$ S \Rightarrow  TabT $$
$$ T \Rightarrow  aT | bT |cT | \epsilon $$

Because we can have any words between the $ab$ that means whatever I do it will still be ambiguous. For example, if I have the starting terminal ab in (ab) so you can recognize them, I can have both $(ab)ab$ and $ab(ab)$

The only solution I can think of is to use brackets which is not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Define the grammar as:

$$S\Rightarrow PabT$$

where $P$ is any string that does not contain $ab$ and $T$ is any string.

$P$ is a little tricky, but not that tricky.

Comment: So P would be something like $P \Rightarrow aH | bP | cP | \epsilon$ and $H \Rightarrow aP|cP|\epsilon$ since the only way we can get a string with an $ab$ is an $a$ followed by a $b$. Seems good?